# ZeroMQ knows which go routine a request came from

Tags: go, zeromq

I am trying to figure out if i have two routines calling the same zeromq socket if when the return from socket.recv() on routine1 returns.. the socket will know to return to routine1 (ditto for routine2, ... routinen).

Hence... using a messaging bus with request/response semantics, what is the best pattern to approach this in go?

If it helps.. think about the simple pirate pattern and implementing an RPC style call set in that pattern with zeromq.

```
Socket; //zeromq socket
//routine 1
socket.send(data) // do i need some identifier here for this routine?
socket.recv() // wait until i get a response from that send
//routine 2 
socket.send(data)
socket.recv()
```

so in this case i have no idea if the response from routine1 or routine2 will come back first. How can i make sure that when i get a response to socket... i can notify the correct routines' recv() function.

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide more of your code, or at least a more fully fleshed out example.  Are you intending to do this in one thread or multiple threads?  What socket types are you using both on this (client?) end and on the peer that you're messaging with?  How are you connecting/binding?  What distinguishes one "routine" from another "routine" in your code/data?  There are any number of possible solutions depending on the answers to these questions.

Comment: I have zero experience/knowledge of ZeroMQ, but in the past when I had multiple goroutines making requests over a shared websocket I had a central goroutine where requests where actually written and responses read. That function had an input channel (of {request, response channel}), a map of the outstanding request ids (generated in sequence) and just used that map to find the appropriate channel to send the response body on (or to log and drop it if there was no map entry).

Comment: Well, I have zero experience/knowledge of Go, so don't we make a pair :). If you haven't read [The Guide](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all) I highly recommend you do so, there are all sorts of examples in Go throughout the document (whenever you see a code sample, there will be a link to a version in many different languages, with a quick glance it appears that most of them have a Go variant).  You'll probably see what you're trying to do, and see an example of it being done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe a socket can be shared, concurrently, between threads using zeromq

Likely you need to do some kind of goroutine that listens for requests, sends / receives zmq, and then replies.

for example: (untested code)

```
type Req struct {
   Data []byte 
   Reply chan []byte
}

go func() { // probably not the zmq api, but you should get the idea here
    for req := <- requests {
         socket.send(req.Data)
         req.Reply <- socket.recv() 
    }
}
```

Comment: the other option is to have a socket for sending and a socket for recv. One being REP and the other REQ. Having them on separate routines to process the data.